# open link in a new tab using Link Next.js component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to open a link in a new tab using Link Next.Js component without using the a tag ?
I have tried the following but it did not work with me

```
<Link target="_blank" href={URL}></Link
```

The above code still opens the link at the same page.

I have also tried this

```
<Link href={URL}>
<a target="_blank"></a>
</Link>
```

this one gave me an error too "Multiple children were passed to  with `href`"

so is there a way around for that ?

Comment: Can you try printing out your "URL" value before or try make it blank and see if things will work correctly!?

Comment: @MohammadTbeishat it still doesnt work if i add it after, and if i keep just the target it gets a props error

Comment: Just for testing just add a static value like href="/". I use it the same way and it works correctly! If it did work, print your URL value and see if it's the result you want!

Comment: Just realized you put the correct code in your second answer. There's something wrong with your 'url' object. If it's just a string, there's no need for the curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In your code sample:**

```
<Link href={URL}>
  <a target="_blank"></a>
</Link>
```

You've got error: `Multiple children were passed to with href`
So it's very likely that you are having some extra spaces between your `<Link/>` and `<a/>` tag. Double-check that or re-format would help.

**But Nextjs `<Link>` is for internal app navigation, and to take full advantage of Nextjs's [prefetch feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerprefetch) and build-in routing**

If you don't need it, just use a normal `<a>` tag:

```
<a target="_blank" href={URL}></a>
```

Comment: THIS. If you use the link like this, it'll reload the app. Just use an external <a> tag in lieu of the internal Link component.

Comment: @JoelHager well one of the requirements is to use Link component so Im looking for a way to open a new tab using Link

Comment: @Ryan so no way I can use _blank with Link component ? it has to be a tag ?

Comment: I am wondering what type of requirement forces you to decide what to use to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @LietoAhmad, There might be some extra spaces in your `<Link>` component. I updated the answer, see if it works for you.

Comment: Not using the Link component caused me a lot of troubles in the past! Especially when I enter to the link directly or refresh the page and not navigate through the website!

Comment: @RyanLe Thank you code worked, I had a mistake earlier that caused the error, but its solved now, just had to wrap the component with the a tag inside of the Link tag